# Undefined array key "idVisiteur"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I was creating a crontoler with the purpose to add new data inside my database. However I get this error message.

Undefined array key "idVisiteur"

Here is my Controler's code:

```
public function FicheFrais() {

        $idVisiteur = $_GET['idVisiteur'];
        $mois = $_GET['mois'];

        $modele = new \App\Models\Modele();
        $donnees = $modele->verifRens($idVisiteur, $mois);
        $data['resultat'] = $donnees;

        if ($data) {

            $sql = 'UPDATE FraisForfait 
        SET quantite = :montant WHERE idVisiteur = :id_visiteur AND mois = :mois AND idFraisForfait = "ETP",
        UPDATE LigneFraisForfait SET quantite = :montant WHERE idVisiteur = :id_visiteur AND mois = :mois AND idFraisForfait = "KM",
        UPDATE LigneFraisForfait SET quantite = :montant WHERE idVisiteur = :id_visiteur AND mois = :mois AND idFraisForfait = "NUI",
        UPDATE LigneFraisForfait SET quantite = :montant WHERE idVisiteur = :id_visiteur AND mois = :mois AND idFraisForfait = "REP"';
        exit;

        } else {

            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM FraisForFrait WHERE idVisiteur = ? AND mois = ?';
            exit;

        }

    }
```

Any idea on how to resolve it ?

I tried to delete

```
 $idVisiteur = $_GET['idVisiteur'];
 $mois = $_GET['mois'];
```

Wich lend me a

```
Undefined variable $idVisiteur
Undefined variable $mois
```

Expect that I tried nothing else.

Comment: If you want to use $_GET variables, then when you make a request to this script, you need to include the appropriate values in the URL to match what the code is looking for. There is a simple example [in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), unsurprisingly. If you are getting the "undefined array key" error for your $_GET array, it must mean you simply did not include these values in the URL when you requested the PHP script.

Comment: I think you SQL also is invalid.